# why my code work on debug mode but don't work in real time

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

what i am having is a java code with a connection to a web service i am trying to add some data to a page .. and when i make a debug the code works just fine but when i try to run it in a real time i face some problems .. here is my java code :

```
public class PersonalInfo extends Activity{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    EditText addressnew;
     GPSTracker gps;
     boolean loginStatus;
     String Item_Name;
     String Item_Price;
     String Item_Quantity;
     String Total_Price;
     String Customer_Name;
     String Customer_Number;
     String Customer_Address;
        ArrayList<String> mixlist=new ArrayList<String>();


     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.personal_info);
           final EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
           final EditText mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
           addressnew=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
           final Button locationnew=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
           Button send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

      send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{
                Intent newintent = getIntent();
                mixlist=newintent.getStringArrayListExtra("listmix");
                Log.e("listmix",mixlist+"");
                for(int i=0;i<=mixlist.size();i++){
                    if(i==mixlist.size()){
                         Item_Name="0";

                            Item_Price="0";

                            Item_Quantity="0";

                            Total_Price="0";

                            Customer_Name=name.getText().toString();
                            Log.e("customer_name",Customer_Name);
                            Customer_Number=mobile.getText().toString();
                            Customer_Address=addressnew.getText().toString();

                            //Call execute 
                            AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                            task.execute(); 
                    }
                    else{
                Item_Name=mixlist.get(i);
                i++;
                Item_Price=mixlist.get(i);
                i++;
                Item_Quantity=mixlist.get(i);
                i++;
                Total_Price=mixlist.get(i);

                Customer_Name="0";
                Customer_Number="0";
                Customer_Address="0";

//              AsyncCallWSnew tasknew = new AsyncCallWSnew();
                //Call execute 
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


//         mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);



//       locationnew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {

//          } 
//           });
//      
//          

     } 
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(PersonalInfo.this,MainActivity.class);

        setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(setIntent);
     }  
     private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                //Make Progress Bar invisible

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "order has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intObj = new Intent(PersonalInfo.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intObj);
                //Error status is false
            }


            //Make Progress Bar visible
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(Item_Name,Item_Price,Item_Quantity, Total_Price, Customer_Name,  

               Customer_Number, Customer_Address,"InsertData");
                return null;
            }          
        }         
}
```

now for example the the mix list is :

```
[orange, 2, 3, 6.0, Tomato, 0.3, 6, 1.7999999999999998]
```

it will add the first for indexes for the item name, item price, item_quantity, total_price and then the other values (customer-name=0 , customer_number=0, customer_address=0) and preform the asynctask and after the array finish it will do the opposite that i will fill (item name, item price, item_quantity, total_price ) = 0 and the other values will be taken from edit texts .. and preform the asynctask .. in the debug mode it works just fine .. in the real time it reverse the values like in this array it will only add  orange, 2, 3, 6.0 and the other three values will be repeated twice !!

please why this is happening??

Comment: Hint: Background threads used for async tasks run even if the main thread is suspended in debugger.

Comment: I didn't have the energy to understand your problem or code but still gave a hint which can explain why code involving async tasks behaves differently when debugged and run normally. Race condition.

Comment: so what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You r creating multiple objects of async task in for loop where each object runs on a separate thread
which runs parallely, and it can happen possibly that your second thread finishes first and first thread finishes in last or in any order, and this is why they are not inserting data in right order but in random order.

Comment: do you have any advice to control it?